# How to wait until element present?

Tags: selenium-ide

I want my Selenium IDE case test to wait 10 secs for the element id = "successed" to appear, and fail the test if it won't happen within 10 secs

This is what I wrote;

```
Selenium.prototype.doWaitForElementIdToAppear = function(){
    selenium.doWaitForCondition("selenium.assertElementNotPresent(\"id=successed\")", "10000");
}
```

...but it never fails.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved this way, using Selenium in-build function

[image: Selenium IDE - this is working]